# Executing custom shell script to build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have setup a jenkins job to build my project. I have a jake.sh file in my project and the code is pulled from github. I want "npm install" command to be executed and then jake.sh to be executed once the the code is checked out.

How can I configure this in jenkins? I have tried givin ./jake.sh and jake.sh in Build->Execute Shell section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According what you tell I think the problem can be

- The script is not marked as a executable. In this case add in  **Build -> Execute Shell** (in case you have linux) `sudo chmod 777 path_to_script/jake.sh`.
- The script is not in the base directory. Remembeber that when you execute a bash script, the current directory is `/path_to_job/workspace`. So you have first to move to the script folder (`cd path_to_script`) or specify the path when running it: `./path_to_script/jake.sh`.

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for shell scripts can be to run the script as

```
bash ./jake.sh
```

instead of

```
./jake.sh
```

Then you don't have to do `chmod`. Useful when you wipe the workspace before every build.

In the same manner, if you have a nodejs shell script or python script, you can run `node myscript.js` / `python myscript.py`.